# How to compile drivers for Centos 7 with mainline kernel 4.5.0.0-1 from @elrepo-kernel

Tags: yum, centos7, linux-kernel, repository, kernel-modules

When using CENTOS 7 with Kernel 4.5, I can not yum install kernel-headers with the same kernel version. I am stuck on 3.10, which is what Centos comes with. How can I install Kernel-headers 4.5 and Kernel-devel which is needed for compiling drivers?

The packages are not in a repo with the mainline kernel updates:

```
[root@localhost tmp]# yum list | grep kernel
kernel-ml.x86_64                        4.5.0-1.el7.elrepo             @elrepo-kernel
abrt-addon-kerneloops.x86_64            2.1.11-36.el7.centos           base     
erlang-kernel.x86_64                    R16B-03.16.el7                 epel     
kernel.x86_64                           3.10.0-327.13.1.el7            updates  
kernel-abi-whitelists.noarch            3.10.0-327.13.1.el7            updates  
kernel-debug.x86_64                     3.10.0-327.13.1.el7            updates  
kernel-debug-devel.x86_64               3.10.0-327.13.1.el7            updates  
kernel-devel.x86_64                     3.10.0-327.13.1.el7            updates  
kernel-doc.noarch                       3.10.0-327.13.1.el7            updates  
kernel-headers.x86_64                   3.10.0-327.13.1.el7            updates  
kernel-tools.x86_64                     3.10.0-327.13.1.el7            updates  
kernel-tools-libs.x86_64                3.10.0-327.13.1.el7            updates  
kernel-tools-libs-devel.x86_64          3.10.0-327.13.1.el7            updates  
libreport-plugin-kerneloops.x86_64      2.1.11-32.el7.centos           base     
lirc-disable-kernel-rc.x86_64           0.9.1a-4.el7                   epel     
php-symfony-http-kernel.noarch          2.7.10-1.el7                   epel     
texlive-l3kernel.noarch                 2:svn29409.SVN_4469-38.el7     base     
texlive-l3kernel-doc.noarch             2:svn29409.SVN_4469-38.el7     base     
[root@localhost tmp]# uname -a
Linux localhost.localdomain 4.5.0-1.el7.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Mar 14 10:24:58 EDT 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@localhost tmp]#
```

Comment: You install the headers from elrepo, of course.

Comment: I can not install from the el-repo, these packages are not there: see edit

Comment: Looks like you disabled the elrepo repo. Try enabling it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you notice that the name of the kernel package you installed was `kernel-ml`?

Corresponding to that, you need to install `kernel-ml-devel` to get the corresponding kernel source for compiling drivers against your kernel.

You don't need to install any kernel headers other than this.

Comment: No package kernel-ml-devel available. -- and kernel-headers is a requirement of gcc, is it not? Yum tries to install kernel-headers 3.10

Comment: Then you need to re-enable the repo, as I already said!

Comment: I don't understand, as I didn't disable it when following a guide to enable it in the first place. I see now that those packages are enabled, will gcc take kernel-ml-headers?

Comment: I guess when i installed kernel-ml it used the repo through the --enablerepo flag. actually enabling the repo fixed the issue of installing kernel-ml development packages, and for those looking to an answer, yes: gcc will take kernel-ml-headers.